# Natural Logarithm Function inequality

Tags: calculus

Using the natural logarithm function, prove that for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$,
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq \ln (n+1)-\ln (n)\leq \frac{1}{n}$$

I tried to integrate this $\ln (n+1)-\ln (n)$ and showed that it's equal to $\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}$.   But how do I link this to the above?

Comment: If you integrated $\log(i+1)-\log i$ and got ${1\over i+1}-{1\over i}$, then you have some highly unusual integration going on.

Comment: Please edit your question: Do you mean $\frac{1}{i+1}$? And if $\ln(i+1)-\ln(i) > \frac{1}{i}$ then it is trivially $>\frac{1}{i+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use the the corollary to [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$$
1+x\le e^x\tag{1}
$$
and take logs to get
$$
\log(1+x)\le x\tag{2}
$$
Then we get
$$
\log(n+1)-\log(n)=\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)\le\frac1n\tag{3}
$$
We also get
$$
\log(n)-\log(n+1)=\log\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)\le-\frac1{n+1}\tag{4}
$$
Combining $(3)$ and $(4)$ yields
$$
\frac1{n+1}\le\log(n+1)-\log(n)\le\frac1n\tag{5}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the definition of logarithm as integral, you have
$$
\log(x+1)-\log x=\int_x^{x+1}\frac{1}{t}\,dt
$$
and can recall the fact that, for a continuous function $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$, one has
$$
m\le\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(t)\,dt\le M
$$
where $m$ and $M$ are the maximum and minimum values of $f$ in $[a,b]$.

Comment: to find $m$ and $M$ do i differentiate ?

Comment: @Fred The function $x\mapsto 1/x$ is decreasing.

Comment: I don't understand. Then how do i link that to prove the equality ?

Comment: @Fred If $f$ is decreasing in $[a,b]$, then $m=f(b)$ and $M=f(a)$.